# Python script output modification with bash in nextflow

Tags: python, arrays, bash, nextflow

I have a python script (make_chunk.py) that takes an input file from input channel and print 3 arrays.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import sys

data=sys.argv[1]
df=pd.read_csv(data,sep='\t',header=None)
chnk_ult=df[df.columns[3]].max()

chnk_start=np.arange(0,chnk_ult,3000000)
chnk_end=chnk_start+3e6
chnk_arr=np.arange(1,len(chnk_end))
print(chnk_start, chnk_end, chnk_arr)
```

I wanted to create 3 different bash array from the above output. In terminal it is doable. I wanted to use the same commands in the nextflow script to create those arrays which will be used later. So far I have tried:

```
process imputation {
publishDir params.out, mode:'copy'
input:
tuple val(chrom),path(in_haps),path(input_bed),path(refs),path(maps) from imp_ch
output:
tuple("${chrom}"),path("${chrom}.*") into imputed
script:
def (haps,sample)=in_haps
def (bed, bim, fam)=input_bed
def (haplotype, legend, samples)=refs
"""
x="\$(make_chunk.py ${bim})"
eval \$(echo \$x | sed 's|,| |g; s|\\[|list1=(|; s|\\[|list2=(|; s|\\[|list3=(|;s|\\]|)\\n|g;')
start="\$(echo \${list1[@]})"
end="\$(echo \${list2[@]})"
chunks="\$(echo \${list3[@]})"
impute4 -g "${haps}" -h "${haplotype}" -l "${legend}" -m "${maps}" -o "${chrom}.step10.imputed.chunk\${chunks}" -no_maf_align -o_gz -int \${start[\${chunks}]} \${end[\${chunks}]} -Ne 20000 -buffer 1000 -seed 54321
"""
}
```

For the above nextflow process, I am getting the following error:

```
Command error: .command.sh: line 7: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6: syntax error in expression (error token is "1 2 3 4 5 6"
```

But in bash terminal, those commands work fine. Any help with this matter?

Comment: I see in your posting one program, which looks like Python, and one program where I don't recognize the language - at least it does not look like bash to me. Clarify how you **name** these two files, and how you **invoke** the command which produces the error.

Comment: I edited the question specifying names of the scripts. The second one is a nextflow script. The bash commands were modified for nextflow syntax.

Comment: Please indicate which of the lines produce the error.

Answer (score 0):

If your bimfile is just a whitespace seperated file, use the [nextflow operator](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#splitcsv) to so split such files: